# terminal error undefined reference to winmain

Tags: c++

For some reason when I finished installing vscode and I just input a basic hello world but it shows that I have some undefined reference to winmain. I'm sorry I'm pretty new but I really need help with how this works and what to change.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxsdv.png)

I used a video which is this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77v-Poud_io&t=331s and I followed every single step except for where I put my workspace for my folder but I'm pretty sure that's not the problem. Hopefully someone can help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Make sure you save the file before compiling.

Comment: It's a fake error message that g++ produces. The real error is that `main` is missing. This is because you have not saved your file before compiling. See the white circle next to test.cpp in that tab? That means an unsaved file. Maybe you can set up VSCode to automatically save files, IDK.

Comment: Following the [official tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) would be better than a youtube video. I assume you're using code runner? It doesn't seem to save files before building,  using the built in tasks or even better using cmake, make or other build system with a vscode plugin would solve your problem